# AWS mapping instance name and private IPs into dns records resource using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I need to create a set of A record for private IPs of ec2 instances in our account.
I can get the name tags of the instances and their private IPs by using the data resources

```
data "aws_instance" "this" {
  for_each = toset(data.aws_instances.ec2s.ids)
  instance_id = each.value
}
```

And then get create the locals

```
  inst_name = { for id, attributes in data.aws_instance.this : id => attributes.tags["Name"] }
  inst_ip = { for id, attributes in data.aws_instance.this : id => attributes.private_ip }
  nameip_map = {for key in distinct(concat(keys(local.inst_name), keys(local.inst_ip))):
              key => flatten([lookup(local.inst_name, key, []),
                              lookup(local.inst_ip, key, [])
                             ])
          }
```

This gives me the following output (redacted)

```
Changes to Outputs:
  + nameip_map    = {
      + i-00exxxxxxxxxxxxxx = [
          + "svr-sso-backup",
          + "10.10.0.12",
        ]
      + i-01exxxxxxxxxxxxxx = [
          + "svr-fido-controller",
          + "172.31.36.137",
        ]
      + i-02exxxxxxxxxxxxxx = [
          + "svr-head-plts",
          + "10.0.196.130",
        ]
   }
```

Then I plug in the server names and IPs  into the terraform
aws_route53_record resource

```
  for_each = local.nameip_map

  allow_overwrite = true
  zone_id = "Z1XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  name    = each.value[key]
  type    = "A"
  ttl     = 300
  records = each.value[value]
}
```

Running the above terraform gives the following error:

```
 Error: Invalid reference
│ 
│   on main.tf line 47, in resource "aws_route53_record" "internal_domain_names":
│   47:   name    = each.value[key]
│ 
│ A reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute access, specifying the
│ resource name.
╵
╷
│ Error: Invalid reference
│ 
│   on main.tf line 50, in resource "aws_route53_record" "internal_domain_names":
│   50:   records = each.value[value]
│ 
│ A reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute access, specifying the
│ resource name.
╵
```

Clearly i'm using the wrong values for getting the instance names and IPs but cannot figure out what!

Comment: `each.key` and `each.value`.

Comment: You don't need to do any of that conversion in `locals`. You could simply do `for_each = data.aws_instance.this` to create the Route53 records.

Comment: @MarkB could you elaborate on the solution - how would I get the instance name and IP mapping from the `data` resource direct?

Comment: The same way you are getting it in those `for` loops in your `locals` declarations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`local.nameip_map` is a map of lists. So when you iterate over it, it should be:

```
  for_each = local.nameip_map

  allow_overwrite = true
  zone_id = "Z1XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  name    = each.value[0]
  type    = "A"
  ttl     = 300
  records = [each.value[1]]
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect - many thanks